# Each element of a class is a set

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory, alternative-proof

In Moschovakis *Notes on set theory* book there is an exercise that says

> Prove that $A$ is a set if and only if $A$ is a member of a class.

(Here a class is either a set or a unary definite condition.) One direction of the proof is trivial because the "set of all sets" is a class. To prove the other direction I used, literally, the axiom of pairing stated in the book:

> **Axiom of pairing**: for any two objects $x$ and $y$ there is a set who only elements are $x$ and $y$.

Then an element $x$ of a class is an object (of the universe of the theory), and consequently $\{x\}$ is a set. Now using the axiom of union we find that $\bigcup\{x\}=x$ is a set.

**QUESTIONS:**

1. It is my proof correct?
2. I find unsatisfying the use of a particular form of the axiom of pairing when, in general, it is not stated for objects if not just for sets. Then, supposing that the above proof is correct, there is som other way to prove the statement?

Comment: You mean the *class* of all sets is a class. And since you're not telling us what are the assumptions, and what does he mean by the word "set", then I'm not sure what you mean. Because for me "set" is equivalent with "exists" or "object" or anything like that. Which renders the exercise trivial. And unfortunately, I left my copy of Moschovakis' book in my other pants.

Comment: @Asaf I see what you mean... It is stated in book this "We call the objects in $\mathcal W$ which are not sets atoms, but we do not require that
any atoms exist, i.e., we allow the possibility that all objects are sets. Definite
conditions and operations are neither sets nor atoms." Where $\mathcal W$ is the universe of objects of the theory of ZF. Because proper classes are defined in the book as definite properties, what doesn't belong to $\mathcal W$ (as stated shortly above) then it seems to say that any element of the universe is a set, and because $\mathcal W$ is a class then...

Comment: However the book says these things almost as comments, what make difficult to follow the formalization of ZF. Also the book seems to differentiate between the universe $\mathcal W$ and the class of all sets, what makes all very confusing. In short: I guess a need a book that show the topic of ZF more formally.

Comment: Kunen's "Set Theory: An Introduction To Independence Proofs" has a formal development of ZF, (I am sure there  are texts for this.)  with some discussion of alternate set theories.